# Dynamically find last cell with text in every row

Tags: excel, vba

I need to add a feature to a macro I created and I am having some trouble doing so.  This is my first post on here!  My macro is a SLA report for tickets.  The last columns (furthest to the right in the spreadsheet) have repeating headers of ACTION TYPE, and ACTION DATE as seen below:

```
ACTION DATE | ACTION TYPE | ACTION DATE | ACTION TYPE | ACTION DATE | ACTION TYPE
```

This is where it becomes dynamic because for every row, there is a unique # of columns which is dependent on the number of Action's performed.

Below would be a simple example where 3 actions occur with a ticket, ie: 1. Submit from requester, 2. Comment, and 3. Close of ticket -- Note: This is 6 columns because before every ACTION TYPE column there is the corresponding ACTION DATE showing when the action occurred:

```
7/14/2015 6:21:19 PM | Submitted | 7/15/2015 9:35 | Commented | 7/15/2015 9:17 | Approved/Closed
```

WHAT I NEED VBA TO DO for this portion is to find when every ticket was closed.  This would be the last populated ACTION DATE cell in every row, assuming the ticket was closed.  This could be done a number of different ways, but I was thinking to find the last cell that contains data (furthest to right) in every row (this would always be the ACTION TYPE column).  Once this is found, verify that the value has "Approved/Closed" in it (not all tickets are closed), and THEN offset one column to the left to copy the closed time. (paste into a new column, say column A for example).
If the ticket is still open, there will not be an "Approved/Closed" action type as the last used cell in the row..I cant simply just go to the last cell in a row with data and assume that it is closed.

Is this possible to do?  Is there a better way?

The # of rows and columns is always changing (typically around 100 columns and 6000 rows.  The Action Date and Action Type columns usually account for the last 60-70 columns in the report.

Comment: Look at Range(currentrow).Find What="Approved/Closed" Then get the date from the previous column.

Comment: Do closed tickets ever get re-opened?

Comment: @MatthewD  Good question, they do get re-opened.  So it literally would need to be the last cell in the row compared to searching for the first "Approved/Closed"  Thanks for quick response!

Comment: There is a .findnext. You will need a loop. I'm on a phone so it's a bit difficult to answer questions right this minute. I'm sure Tim or somebody can provide and example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it in VBA You could do something like this

```
Dim rw As Range
For Each rw In Range(Range("A1"), Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Cells
    If rw.End(xlToRight).Value = "Approved/Closed" Then
        MsgBox rw.End(xlToRight).Offset(, -1).Value 'put the value anywhere you want.
    End If
Next
```

It will loop through all the rows and check if the last column is equal to "Approved/Closed".  Then you can do what ever wanted with the offset value.

This only works if there are no blank cells in the table.

Comment: You are awesome Scott - Thank you!  How would I get the time value that you are pulling (End(xlToRight).Offset(, -1).Value) into a specific column?  Say column A for every row that it finds the time value in, enter the value to Range A & the row that it is taking the value from.

Comment: You would 'rw.offset(,x)` the x would be the number of rows offset from the column specified in the for loop.  If you are going to put the answer in column A use column B in the for loop and x would equal -1.

Comment: Makes sense!! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Entered in (eg) A3 this will pick up the "closed" date provided the last populated column in the row is "Approved/Closed"

```
=IF(INDEX(3:3,1,MAX((LEN(B3:KZ3)>0)*COLUMN(B3:KZ3)))="Approved/Closed",
    INDEX(3:3,1,MAX((LEN(B3:KZ3)>0)*COLUMN(B3:KZ3))-1),"")
```

An array formula, so use Ctrl+Shift+Enter when entering it.